# How to extend DateElement to display with Year selection

Tags: c#, uidatepicker, monotouch.dialog

I have extended the DateElement with DateTimePicker, DatePicker and TimePicker - depend on the DateTimeMode attribute passed in.

however the problem is i want to add another option which is select year. one way is to create PopoverController.

But is it possible that i can add year selection in DateElement? since i am already subclassing this.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to add a year to the DateElement with something that is already built in.

You may be able to override the `CreatePicker` method and supply your own custom `UIPicker` with a year in it.